# Blender resizing my image in half

Tags: image

I have a problem. I'm trying to render an image and the resolution is 500x280. After I render the image and save it, for some reason the image gets resized to 250x140. I'm unsure why it happends.

Comment: Factory settings have a percentage of the render size set to 50%. Did you already change it to 100%? Can you show your render scene settings?

Comment: Oh, that fixed it! Thanks, I didn't realise it was on 50%.

Answer (score 9):

### Check Render Resolution Percentage

Factory settings have a percentage of the render size set to 50%, that means the to the values in the upper fields , a multiplyer of 0.50 units will be applied.

[image]

This feature it's very handy when it comes to build a quick preview keeping the final output proportions.

I you would like to render in full resolution just enter 100% as percentage.

*Note: beware that the field accepts values also above 100. Count wisely the number of zeros.*